# XDocument.Descendants(itemName) - Problems finding qualified name

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, qualified-name, xname

I'm trying to read a XML-RSS-Feed from a website. Therefore I use a async download and create a `XDocument` with the `XDocument.Parse()` Method.

The Document intends to be very simple, like this:

```
<root>
  <someAttribute></SomeAttribute>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
</root>
```

Now I want to read out all the items. Therefore I tried:

```
foreach (XElement NewsEntry in xDocument.Descendants("item"))
```

but this doesn't work. So I found a post in this board to use the qualified name, because there are some namespaces defined in the root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
```

well, I tried all 3 available namespaces - nothing worked for me:

```
XName itemName = XName.Get("item", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
XName itemName2 = XName.Get("item", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
XName itemName3 = XName.Get("item", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/");
```

Any help would be appreciated.
(Usually I'm doing the XML-Analysis with Regex - but this time I'm developing for a mobile device, and therefore need to care about performance.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not tried the [default namespace](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3720/understanding-xml-namespaces/5/) at the end of the `rdf` declaration:

```
xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
```

This makes sense, as any element in the default namespace will not need to have the namespace prepended to the element name.

Comment: Yeah, that's it - the one solution i didn't expect. Thx very much.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly a solution to the XDocument RSS read problem. But why aren't you using the provided SyncdicationFeed class to load the feed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Comment: looks very interesting. i'll have a look at that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var elements = from p in xDocument.Root.Elements()
where p.Name.LocalName == "item"
select p;

foreach(var element in elements)
{
//Do stuff
}
```